# Save Word file in multiple locations at once

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to save a word file in 5 different locations. My main problem is that my code only works if I specify a name in the save as part. I tried this, but with no luck:

```
  ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
    "O:\xxxx"
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=
    "O:\xxxx" & Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0) & ".doc", _
    , FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
    AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
    :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
    "O:\xxx"
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
    O:\xxxx" & Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0) & ".doc", _
    , FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
    AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
    :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
    "O:\xxx"
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
    O:\xxxx" & Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0) & ".doc", _
    , FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
    AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
    :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
    "O:xxxx"
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
    O:\xxxx" & Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0) & ".doc", _
    , FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
    AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
    :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
    "O:\xxx"
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
    O:\xxxx" & Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0) & ".doc", _
    , FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
    AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
    :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
```

The file paths are all different but the filename should be the same. It basically should just take the name of the opened document.

Answer (score 2):

well, I would do it in a loop:

```
Sub daf()
    Dim docCopy As Document
    Dim sPath(4) As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim i As Long

    sPath(0) = "C:\zzz"
    sPath(1) = "c:\ddd"
    sPath(2) = "C:\ttt"
    sPath(3) = "C:\yyy"
    sPath(5) = "C:\ooo"

    sFileName = Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")(0)
    Set docCopy = Application.Documents.Add(ActiveDocument.FullName)

    For i = 0 To UBound(sPath)
        docCopy.SaveAs2 sPath & "\" & sFileName & ".doc", 12
    Next i

End Sub
```

You can add more arguments to saveAs2 if you wish, as you did in your original macro.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply!
But yeah this worked also. 
I just did it a bit differntly :D